# How to get top results using specifications in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I am quite new to spring data jpa. I am trying to use specifications while querying database. My question is using crudrepository we can method like :

```
findTopByUsernameOrderByUpdatedAtDesc(String username);
```

How can I achieve the same using specifications? I can do basic things like and or in specifications, but not very robust like we can do with criteria etc.

```
Specification<CustomClass> spec = Specifications.where(specification).and(username);
List<CustomClass> list = findAll(spec);
```

Comment: removed the part about asking for tutorials and stuff, because it makes an otherwise good question off topic.

Comment: Actually I would `order` the result list and you get your result in top place.

Comment: you asked with the half information, specification can build with the predicate and Query builders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was done as follows :

```
 Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 1, Sort.Direction.DESC, "username");
 Page oneElementPage = repository.findAll(spec, pageable);
```

This will sort the data on username column in descending direction and return first result.

Answer (score 1):

You can't express this in a `Specification` directly. But you can use a `Pageable` for this:

```
Page oneElementPage = repository.findAll(spec, new PageRequest(0, 1));
```

Gives you a `Page` with a single element.

Comment: Will this be fine :    Pageable pageable = PageRequest(0, 1, Sort.Direction.DESC, "username"); and then pass this to findAll(spec,pageable); ?

Comment: Think so. Just try it.